# Проблема с левой колонкой сайта  WordPress

Tags: cms, php, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Я очень прошу помощи, так как я совсем не опытный в этих делах и уже много времени потратил на решение данной проблемы. Дело в том, что мне необходимо следить за сайтом в WordPress, и я начал разбираться. Сайт делался на заказ без моего участия. Я удалил строчку и случайно сохранил изменения. Она находилась в конце прилагаемого кода вместо комментария. Помогите, пожалуйста, восстановить. Данный код отвечает за вывод боковой колонки (sidebar.php), которая включает в себя меню со страницами сайта и новости (3 последних), т.е. Рубрики. Как раз оттуда я и удалил код. Предположительно, это было что-то вроде query_posts() и вывод 3 новостей в боковую колонку, прямо под меню.
Если нужно предоставить данные из других файлов, вы скажите. Просто работа горит и мне по шее дадут((

```
<?php global $themedata; ?>
<div id="sidebar">
<div class="sidetitle">Навигация</div>
<?php
if (has_nav_menu('sidemenu'))
{
   wp_nav_menu
   (
      array
      (
         'theme_location' => 'sidemenu',
         'container' => '',
         'container_class' => '',
         'menu_class' => 'sidemenu',
         'menu_id' => 'sidemenu',
         'depth' => 2
      )
   );
}
else
{  
   echo '<ul class="sidemenu">';
   wp_list_pages
   (
      array
      (
         'depth' => 2,
         'title_li' => ''
      )
   );  
   echo '</ul>';
}
?>
//тут не хватает части кода (предположительно начинается все с query_posts())
<?php while ($sidenews->have_posts()) { $sidenews->the_post(); include(TEMPLATEPATH.'/inc-sidenews.php'); } ?>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

конец файла sidebar.php

начало  inc-sidenews.php

```
<div>
<span><?php the_time('d F Y'); ?></span>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<p><?php the_short(300); ?>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: ой да благослови вас БОЖе!!! спасибо! вы меня спасли(( я просто пока не особо выучил основы но я буду стараться! спасибо за ваш ответ))этот код и был удален.. я понимаю что я задал тупой вопрос, просто чуть растерялся...

Comment: добавил эти вещи 
<?php { ?>
<?php $sidenews = "cat=" . "&showposts=3"; $sidenews = new WP_Query($sidenews); ?>
и выводит 3 новости как и нужно))) спасибо

Comment: Здорово! Без проблем.

Answer (score 1):

Там точно не одна строчка была удалена. А судя по коду, программер туда много запихнул. Самый простой вариант искать бэкап. По другому вряд ли получится, если не разбирать все по полочкам.
Почитать про query можно тут: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

Answer (score 0):

> Я удалил строчку и случайно сохранил
> изменения.

Так вы удалили строчку или блок кода?

Судя по

```
<?php } ?>
```

где то сверху (в удаленном коде) обязательно должно присутствовать `<?php { ?>`